# Using Subsonic3 with Linqpad

Tags: subsonic3, linqpad

Has anyone been able to get subsonic objects to work in linq pad , the problem i have at the moment is that it cant find the connection string when ever I try to run my code.

I have tried adding the connection string to the linqpad config file as well as copying the original config file from the project that contains the connection string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer to this.  You must create a LinqPad.config (NOT Linqpad.exe.config) in the same directory as LinqPad.exe with the proper `<connectionStrings>` section that SubSonic 3 needs.  Restart Linqpad and you should be off to the races.

Don't forget to use F4 on the queries so you can bring in the proper namespaces and reference the SubSonic.Core.dll.

I'm able to get the queries to run, produce results, etc., but the Linqpad 'SQL' output is blank.

thanks,
mark

Comment: Yeah I found this after contacting support , but couldn't answer the question at the time , thanks for replying

Comment: i tried this but i'm not 'off to the races'... don't see connection string show up. Could you post an example of such a linqpad.config file?